# Como permitir EditText solo con dos decimales?

Tags: edittext

Quiero lograr que el EditText me acepte solamente dos decimales. Si por ejemplo coloco 23.89 ya no me deje agregar otro decimal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lo que debes hacer es crear un InputFilter así:

```
editText.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new InputFilter() {

            DecimalFormatSymbols decimalFormatSymbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols();

            @Override
            public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
                int indexPoint = dest.toString().indexOf(decimalFormatSymbols.getDecimalSeparator());

                if (indexPoint == -1)
                    return source;

                int decimals = dend - (indexPoint+1);
                return decimals < 2 ? source : "";
            }
        }
        });
```

Comment: Eso iría dentro de protected void onCreate, cierto ? Porque compilo bien pero al ejecutar la aplicación se "stopea" antes de iniciarse. Importé esta librería: android.icu.text.DecimalFormatSymbols. Está bien ?

Comment: Anduvo maestro !! Había importado otra librería. Funcionó con import java.text.DecimalFormatSymbols. Mil gracias. Abrazo !

Comment: En un emulador funciona bien y me acepta solo dos decimales. Pero en otro emulador no funciona. A que se debe ? Estuve viendo las API y aparentemente está todo ok. Agradezco la respuesta.